# PHP gives error that is not present when using replit

Tags: php, html, error-handling, argon2-cffi

I was attempting to write a password-protect page in php

```php
<?php
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if(password_verify($user, '$argon2i$v=19$m=2048,t=4,p=3$Y3NGc25QQ1k1cTBkTHZNRg$skaHiTZAiAYB2bwme/KBhRujlJNXWd7jkji4vP5t5zM')) //hash is Admin
{
  header("Location: secure.html");
  exit();
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST))
    {?>

            <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            Pass <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
            </form>
    <?}
}
?>
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
PHP Parse error:  Unclosed '{' on line 15 in /home/cody/Desktop/code/Web/secureSignIn/index.php on line 25
```

This error was not present when working with PHP on Replit. Can anyone explain why this error is showing?

I tried replacing `<?` with `<?php`, adding `<? php error_reporting(0); ?>`, and using `echo` to run the HTML (Which only printed it to console and did not execute.

Comment: `<?` should be `<?php`. You don't have short tags enabled in your PHP configuration, but repl.it does.

Comment: A typo?  The first PHP code block is opened with `<?php`, but the second is opened with just `<?`.  Is your PHP configured to allow the latter?  (If that's even a thing?)  Either way, it's likely best to remain consistent and just use `<?php`.

Comment: I tried that and the error did not change

Comment: You also need a space between `<?php` and `}`. When I changed that line to `<?php }` I didn't get an error.

Comment: "replacing <? with <?php" is referencing line 18

Comment: Ok thank you Bamar, but now I have an error when visiting the website:  127.0.0.1:49270 [404]: GET / - No such file or directory

Comment: Here is the request header: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

- put the <?php starttag in a seperate line
- start again with <?php and not only <?

```
<?php
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if(password_verify($user, '$argon2i$v=19$m=2048,t=4,p=3$Y3NGc25QQ1k1cTBkTHZNRg$skaHiTZAiAYB2bwme/KBhRujlJNXWd7jkji4vP5t5zM')) //hash is Admin
{
    header("Location: secure.html");
    exit();
}  
else
{
    if(isset($_POST))
    {?>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        Pass <input type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```